# Retrieve information from database SQL with Python to display them into an xml page

Tags: python, mysql, xml, odoo

I'm going crazy on this simple stuff and I'm here to ask your help:

I have DB. With many tables. One of them is called product.pricelist.item

I have a web front-end, with an xml template engine (called QWeb) which need to display some field of that table.

Then I have a python back-end (please note that i'm not a python dev, and that's why it's driving me crazy).

This is the python back-end file who throw stuff at the webpage I'm working on (I'm working with Odoo, ex OpenERP) https://fossies.org/dox/odoo-8.0.0/website__sale_2controllers_2main_8py_source.html

As you can see I can easily retrieve information from the table product.template (for example, "product.price", into an xml tag, give me the price of the product). From the product.template table i was able to go up to the pricelist.version table, yet not to the product.pricelist.item table.

Please help

Comment: http://useopenerp.com/v8/model/product-product see this link product.product all relation ships.

Comment: Hi. I'm looking at your link. 
I saw there is a relation between this product.product and the product.pricelist.item model, but i'm a bit confused on how to use it properly. Gonna try in the front-end if the "product_product.pricelist" retrieve something. Thanks for the help